# Im trying to define a function to capitalize a string without using the predefined function

Tags: python

```
def All_uppercase(s):
    x=0
    lst=[]
    while x<=len(s):
        if ord(str(s)[x])>=97:
            lst.append(chr(ord(s[x])-32))
            x+=1
        else:
            x+=1
    print("".join(lst))
    lst
```

for some reason it says string index out of range but im not sure why.

Comment: Your function does not return anything.

Comment: Also, your function fails for any non-alphabetic character with a code >= 97.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the other commenters already suggested, you should avoid using "magic" numbers like 97 and 32. Here is a more Pythonic solution:

```
def all_uppercase(s):
    shift = ord('A') - ord('a')
    return ''.join(chr(ord(c) + shift) if 'a' <= c <= 'z' else c
                   for c in s)
all_uppercase('Hello, world!')
#'HELLO, WORLD!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it `while x<len(s)`, since the last index of `s` will be `len(s)-1`

Answer (score 0):

You have included the len(s) in the while loop if the index starts from 0
So, change the while loop like this:

```
while x<len(s):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while x<=len(s):
```

When x is equal to the lenght of the string the index x is out of range, indexes starts as 0 so:

```
while x<len(s):
```

should fix it.